# "Do you also?" as a question?

Tags: grammar, questions, sentence-patterns

I was able to find numerous examples of "Do you also..." type questions in *The Bible*, like:

> And Yeshua said to the twelve, “Do you also wish to leave?”

But I am wondering whether simply "Do you also?" as a question, if given proper proper context, is correct or not? E.g.:

> I like to live dangerously. Do you also?

Comment: It is a legitimate sentence, given that from the context the listener will fill in "live dangerously".  English is quite tolerant of this sort of thing.

Comment: I think many if not most of a claimed 1760 instances of [**do that too said***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Do+that+too+said%22) will be in contexts like *"I do that too", said John*. By comparison, Google Books has only 6 instances of [*Do that **also** said*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Do+that+also+said%22). Biblical texts don't usually reflect normal speech patterns, which here would favour *And Yeshua said to the twelve, “Do you wish to leave **too**?”* and *I like to live dangerously. Do you too?*

Comment: OK, thank you, FumbleFingers and Hot Licks, very much. My takeaway from your comments is that, although correct, "Do you also?" question sounds less natural than simply "Do you too?", both in proper context, of course. If either of you would like to convert your comment to an answer I'd be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could you put that in an answer, so this question doesn't stay unanswered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I end this sentence with "also" or "too"? Which one is right?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168473/can-i-end-this-sentence-with-also-or-too-which-one-is-right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or one could also say, "Do you?". I tend to live dangerously, do you?  When writing a dialogue, an editor would easily slash right through the end pieces such as "too, also, as well" and any others that seem to break the flow of a normal conversation.  Depending on the flavor, period, or ethnicity of those speaking, it could easily end with "You?" "Do you my friend?" "How about you?"